# What's the equivalent of a DO block for Postgres < 9.0

Tags: postgresql

What's the Postgres 8.4.8 equivalent of

```
DO $$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (...) THEN
    EXECUTE ...;
END IF;
END; $$;
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create function f() returns void as $$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (...) THEN
    EXECUTE ...;
END IF;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

select f();
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like a function definition; doesn't the `DO` block also *execute* the function?  IOW, wouldn't I need also an explicit call to `f`?

Comment: @kjo Not a call to f but a select. Edited.