# postgresql: syntax error at or near "DO"

Tags: postgresql, syntax, plpgsql, procedure

I am trying to run a DO block, e.g. this one (copied from a post in this forum)

```
DO $$
DECLARE x int;
    BEGIN
    x := 10;
    RAISE NOTICE '>>>%<<<', x;
END;
$$
```

but what happens is:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DO"
>
> SQL state: 42601
>
> Character: 1

It doesn't matter, what DO block I run, the DO statement is simply not working (including on examples copy/pasted from the doucment, and I wonder what could be the reason. Could anybody help me, please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of postgres?

Comment: Well, I can guess anyway. `DO` was added in postgres 9.0. For older versions see [What's the equivalent of a DO block for Postgres < 9.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260725/whats-the-equivalent-of-a-do-block-for-postgres-9-0)

Comment: Either 9.3. or a later version.

Comment: Show the output of `select version();`

Comment: I am sorry. It is 8.4.20. I am working on a newly installed server and it didn't occur to me that an earlier version could have been installed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running on an old version of PostgreSQL.

In general, if you get an unexpected syntax error on a keyword or PostgreSQL complains about a missing function that should obviously exist, the first thing to do is check that the feature you're trying to use actually existed in your version.

You can replace a `DO` block with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_func() RETURNS void AS 
$$
.. body of the DO block here...
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT some_func();

DROP FUNCTION some_func();
```

in an older version.

Comment: this is not entirely true. I get the same error on PostgreSQL 14, came here searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same error with postgreSQL 9.0+, then it is due to the wrong execute type. pgAdiminIII has two execute (green triangle) buttons:

- Execute Query
- Execute pgScript

In order to run `DO $$` you need the first one.